What are the possible ways we can handle the case when the setup code of a test fixture requires to be tested itself?
What are the possible ways we can handle the case when the setup code of a test fixture requires to be tested itself? Consider the following code in C# 12.0/.NET 8.0 and NUnit (But the answer could probably be used in most testing frameworks and programming languages):
// Usings and namespace have been abbreviated away.
[TestFixture]
public class Foo
{
    private Bar? _bar;
 
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _bar = DoApiRequest("endpoint"); // The problem here is that the API request needs to be tested itself, also this can be anything, not just an API request.
        // ...
    }
    // Other tests
    // ...
}

We could try to add asserts in the setup:
// Usings and namespace have been abbreviated away.
[TestFixture]
public class Foo
{
    private Bar? _bar;
 
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _bar = DoApiRequest("endpoint"); // The problem here is that the API request needs to be tested.
        // Assert code here which makes the setup basically a test itself that other tests depend on.
        // ...
    }
    // Other tests
    // ...
}

How can I test the API used in the setup of all my other tests first without creating a dependency between tests and still be able to run my tests in parallel?

Just create test only with assertions assuring setup executed as expected

@MichałTurczyn Yes, but tests run in parallel, I want that test with the assertions to the setup to run before every other test. Consider making this an answer instead of a comment.

Usually it is considered bad practice if tests depend on other test and i could not find any solution to that problem

I would just create test with assertions:
[TestMethod]
public void TestSetup()
{
    // Test the API request that needs to be tested.
    // Assert.Something(_bar)
}

EDIT To answer question with separated tests for setups, I can only suggest creating separate project where would be base test classes with Setup and TestSetup method. Then those base test classes could be inherited in unit test classes.
I would suggest such implementation:
Project NUnit.Tests.Setups:
public interface IBaseTest
{
    public void Setup();

    public void TestSetup();
}

public interface IBar { }

public class BaseBarTest : IBaseTest
{
    protected IBar Bar;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Bar = new Mock<IBar>().Object;
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        Assert.NotNull(Bar);
    }
}

Project NUnit.Tests:
public class BarTest : BaseBarTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.NotNull(Bar);
    }
}

Then you can run unit tests separately for setups and for actual unit tests.

Re: closure. This is a technical question and can be answered as such. By closing it rapidly because you fear opinions will arise, you prevent those who actually understand the question and the specifics of the software from giving such answers.

I have edited the question, even though it was clear enough to me in the first place. SO folks seem too quick to close IMO. It would be much easier to get the needed clarification by dialog with the questioner than by shutting them out. I realize there's probably another place to express this opinion but I'm a casual SO user and answering and commenting is all I know how to do. :-)

@Hashkoon I edited to remove mention of "best practices" because that's a matter of opinion and opinion-based questions are usually closed on SO. In my opinion, however it's a good question so I edited it to say what I think you intended... i.e. this is what I want to do, tell me how to do it? If I didn't get exactly what you meant, you should re-edit the question - but don't ask for anyone's opinion. :-)

@Charlie Thank you, I do not think this question should really be closed like that, "best practices" actually are opinion based, but not really at the same time. Things like tests depending on each other are objectively proven to be a bad thing for obvious reasons, whoever closed it like a spam filter, just examining patterns.

Well, this works, but I think it is weird to implement such a thing yourself like that, so I will only accept your answer if there is a way to do it that is actually built into NUnit.

@Hashkoon Well I doubt that NUnit Has such implementation. But i am curious if you would find one ;)
